# query sql SUM only 1 value on duplicate value with JOIN

Tags: mysql

I have problem again with query of sql.

I have 2 table. 'transactions' table and 'transactaion_detail' tabel.

transactions as trx

```
ID    TOTAL
1     2000
2     10000
3     5000
```

transactions_details as td

```
ID    trx_id     PRICE
1       1        2000
2       2        5000
3       2        5000
4       3        1000
5       3        2000
6       3        2000
```

when I query like this

```
select sum(trx.total) from transactions as trx
join transaction_details as td
on trx.id = td.trx_id
```

I got result

**37000**

thats result that is not what I meant.

because when I change sum(trx.total) to trx.*

the data show like this

```
ID    TOTAL
1     2000
2     10000
2     10000
3     5000
3     5000
3     5000
```

I want get result **17000** from that query.

I know I can just sum price on table transaction_detail or sum total on transcations without join another table. but in my case I have to join 2 table and SUM.

please help me

Answer (score 0):

You can first aggregate second table and then join -

```
SELECT SUM(PRC)
FROM transactions T
JOIN (SELECT trx_id, SUM(PRICE) PRC
      FROM transactions_details
      GROUP BY trx_id) TD ON T.id = TD.trx_id
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `GROUP BY` , change your query like following.

```
SELECT trx.id
    ,sum(trx.total)
FROM transactions AS trx
JOIN transaction_details AS td ON trx.id = td.trx_id
GROUP BY trx.id
```